# intelliJ Including Resource Folders in Classpath

Tags: intellij-idea, classpath

previously with Tomcat 7.0.85 I was able to include the resource folders (including properties etc..) for my project using "-Xbootclasspath/a"

But now I had to switch to Tomcat 9.0.19 and I do again include the folders using above jvm argument. This time it does not take any effect.

## Workarounds

```
#1 to include all related resource files in delivered war file. But thatprevents the external configuration freedom.

#2 put all files into the lib folder of tomcat instance. This less harmfull but still makes the lib folder dirty.
```

Comment: How would you do it from the command line, outside of IntelliJ IDEA? IDE just runs Tomcat startup script.

Comment: Not exactly. You can give extra VM arguments via  `Run Config -> VM Options`

Comment: There is a related feature request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134047.